# sharepoint webpart javascript - 'null' is null or not an object

Tags: 2007, javascript, web-part, web-part-pages

I have an issue on one of my sharepoint enviriontments regarding some kind of javascript problem with the Content Editor Web Part which keeps returning me these errors when I try to user the RTF-text editor:

### First

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 5739
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://URL/_layouts/1033/HtmlEditor.js
```

### Second

```
Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 2325
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://URL/_layouts/1033/form.js?rev=df60y6YolDjUVbi91%2BZw%2Fg%3D%3D
```

I have tried to follow the following solution guides from bloggers etc:

- http://sharepointsharpener.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/script-error-in-rtf-editor-work-around/
- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30654105/content-editor-web-part-javascript-error-with-more-than-2-on-a-pag.aspx
- http://www.benstegink.com/2009/05/21/javascript-error-editing-web-parts-on-a-sharepoint-page/

But none of them seemed to help me. They made my troubleshooting a lot easier and helped me figure what I should google some more towards, but I have not yet found a solution.

Have any of you experienced the same problem, and how did you solve it?

**Edit** (request from @omlin)

The errors occurs on all sites on the website. Every page is using pure standard pagelayouts, no custom masterpage is used. I have some custom webparts on the pages, but that has no influence as the error occurs on blank pages too. I tried changing the language packages from English to Danish and vice versa, but no effect. So I'm clueless whatsoever about this.

Comment: Please, provide additional information: do you get this errors on all possible pages, even on completely blank, or only on pages with your customizations/webparts? Do you have masterpage customizations? Did you try to create new blank site collection and add CEWP on blank page there?

Comment: What browser(s) have you tested? Tried clearing the cache? Tried different client machines?

Comment: What exactly is the line of js that is throwing an error? could you post it here? I only have SP2010 running at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem is isolated to one environment, no additional JavaScript files are included, and the issue arises on even blank pages, I would recommend the following:

- Ensure none of the SharePoint JavaScript files have been modified directly (shudder):

  - a) Check none of the modification dates are much later than expected
  - b) Use a comparison tool to find any differences between that environment's JavaScript files and an unmodified installation
- Check no other JavaScript files have been included by other means:

  - Track the loaded files in the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools (or similar), and compare to an identical page on an unmodified server.

Unfortunately these are hand-wavey suggestions, rather than specifically targeted at your issue. It seems the more specific resolutions have been unsuccessful, so starting again from a more general standpoint (as in the above) may help you track it down.